# Reference patterns might not always be irrefutable?

Tags: rust

> Reference patterns are always irrefutable.

From [Patterns - The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html#reference-patterns)

The reference show this code.

```
let int_reference = &3;

let a = match *int_reference { 0 => "zero", _ => "some" };
let b = match int_reference { &0 => "zero", _ => "some" };

assert_eq!(a, b);
```

If reference patterns would be irrefutable, then the `_ => "some"` arm would never execute since `&0` is irrefutable and matching anything, but of course this is not true.

It seems like for me is that reference pattern is **only** irrefutable if the subpattern is irrefutable. For example `&x` (identifier pattern) would be indeed irrefutable since `x` is irrefutable.

Am I right or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. Reference patterns **by themselves** are irrefutable, but other parts of the whole pattern may be refutable.